# Bitwise permutation of multiple 64bit values in parallel / combined 

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, permutation, bit-shift

**This question is NOT about "How do i bitwise permutation" We now how to do that, what we are looking for is a faster way with less cpu instructions, inspired by the bitslice implementation of sboxes in DES**

To speed up some cipher code we want to reduce the amount of permutation calls. The main cipher functions do multiple bitwise permutations based on lookup arrays. As the permutation operations are only bitshifts,

Our basic idea is to take multiple input values, that need the same permutation, and shift them in parallel. For example, if input bit 1 must be moved to output bit 6.

Is there any way to do this? We have no example code right now, because there is absolutly no idea how to accomplish this in a performant way.

The maximum value size we have on our plattforms are 128bit, the longest input value is 64bit.Therefore the code must be faster, then doing the whole permutation 128 times.

**EDIT**

Here is a simple 8bit example of a permutation

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | <= Bits
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | <= Input
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | 8 | 6 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 7 | <= Output
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The cipher makes usage of multiple input keys. It's a block cipher, so the same pattern must be applied to all 64bit blocks of the input.

As the permutations are the same for each input block, we want to process multiple input blocks in one *step* / to combine the operations for multiple input sequences. Instead of moving 128times one bit per call, moving 1 time 128bit at once.

**EDIT2**

We could NOT use threads, as we have to run the code on embedded systems without threading support. Therefore we also have no access on external libraries and we have to keep it plain C.

**SOLUTION**

After testing and playing with the given answers we have done it the following way:

- We are putting the single bits of 128 64bit values on a uint128_t[64]* array.
- For permutation we have just to copy pointers
- After all is done, we revert the first operation and get 128 permuted values back

Yeah, it is realy that simple. We was testing this way early in the project, but it was too slow. It seems we had a bug in the testcode.

Thank you all, for the hints and the patience.

Comment: Can you list more examples? That 'To take multiple input values, that need the same permutation, and shift them in parallel' is not quite clear.

Comment: You say you're using an embedded platform - which one? The capabilities of your CPU are obviously going to be a significant factor here.

Comment: Only for the permutation stage, the bit-slicing solution of Nemo doesn't seem to be faster (if I understood it right, Version B in http://ideone.com/OYORo should give you the bit-slicing method). But I think he's right in saying: "implement all of the stages on the bit-slice representation". Here should arise an advantage in my opinion.

Comment: @Nick There is a NDA, preventing me from telling to much. But i could tell you, our systems have native support for `or`,`and`,`xor`,`nand`,`nor`, addressing modes from 8bit to 128bit, and 256 128bit registers.

Comment: @Christian thx for the work to compare the runtimes. We'll have a try again with bitslicing. We had tried that already, and it was much slower than in you example. So, well have a look if there is any issue with the code.

Comment: @Thomas It seems likely that SIMD type instructions are one way this might be optimized, but it's impossible to say which are possible without knowing the target platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make Stan's bit-by-bit code faster by using eight look-up tables mapping bytes to 64-bit words.  To process a 64-bit word from input, split it into eight bytes and look up each from a different look-up table, then OR the results.  On my computer the latter is 10 times faster than the bit-by-bit approach for 32-bit permutations.  Obviously if your embedded system has little cache, then <strike>32 kB</strike> 16 kB of look-up tables may be a problem.  If you process 4 bits at a time, you only need 16 look-up tables of 16*8=128 bytes each, i.e. 2 kB of look-up tables.

EDIT: The inner loop could look something like this:

```
void permute(uint64_t* input, uint64_t* output, size_t n, uint64_t map[8][256])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*)(input+i);
        output[i] = map[0][p[0]] | map[1][p[1]] | map[2][p[2]] | map[3][p[3]]
            | map[4][p[4]] | map[5][p[5]] | map[6][p[6]] | map[7][p[7]];
    }
}
```

Comment: As i have to move the bits from any to any position i could not split up input and ouput to 8bit. And we have to use bit by bit, because its a **BITWISE** cipher ...

Comment: Note that the idea is to map a byte into a 64 bit word, just to allow moving bits anywhere within a 64-bit word.  As long as you don't need to move a bit into another 64-bit word, it works fine.

Comment: Then, you should provide an example, because i could not imagine how right now

Comment: I added an example implementation of the inner loop. Setting up the look-up tables is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: I know how it works, but read the last update on my question. This is not faster than doing it in a serial way. Event the lookups in the maps require more instructions, then shifting every of the 64 inputs serial with fixed shift instructions.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the processor.  I added the code to Christian Ammer's benchmark (as version C) with the following results: Version A Time = 0.675184; Version B Time = 1.3193;
Version C Time = 0.016659

Comment: thx for the informations, I have just one little logical problem with you above examples. How do i make sure the output bits gets to the direct position. Which why the array was prepared, so you could only use `or` without shifts?

Comment: The shifts are precomputed in the look-up table. If you've got a function `permute_word` that performs the desired 64-bit permutation, then `map[i][x] = permute_word((uint64_t)x<<(8*i)))` on a little-endian machine.

Comment: thx, we are working on a benchmark for you platform right now, testing all suggestions made here. May the fastest win ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for a [bit-slicing implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_slicing#Modern_use).  This is how the fastest DES-cracking impelmentations work.  (Or it was before SSE instructions existed, anyway.)

The idea is to write your function in a "bit-wise" manner, representing each output bit as a Boolean expression over the input bits.  Since each output bit depends only on the input bits, any function can be represented this way, even things like addition, multiplication, or S-box lookups.

The trick is to use the actual bits of a single register to represent *a single bit from multiple input words*.

I will illustrate with a simple four-bit function.

Suppose, for example, you want to take four-bit inputs of the form:

```
x3 x2 x1 x0
```

...and for each input, compute a four-bit output:

```
x2 x3 x2^x3 x1^x2
```

And you want to do this for, say, eight inputs.  (OK for four bits a lookup table would be fastest.  But this is just to illustrate the principle.)

Suppose your eight inputs are:

```
A = a3 a2 a1 a0
B = b3 b2 b1 b0
...
H = h3 h2 h1 h0
```

Here, `a3 a2 a1 a0` represent the four bits of the `A` input, etc.

First, encode all eight inputs into four bytes, where each byte holds one bit from each of the eight inputs:

```
X3 =  a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 f3 g3 h3
X2 =  a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 f2 g2 h2
X1 =  a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1
X0 =  a0 b0 c0 d0 e0 f0 g0 h0
```

Here, `a3 b3 c3 ... h3` is the eight bits of `X3`.  It consists of the high bits of all eight inputs.  `X2` is the next bit from all eight inputs.  And so on.

Now to compute the function eight times in parallel, you just do:

```
Y3 = X2;
Y2 = X3;
Y1 = X2 ^ X3;
Y0 = X1 ^ X2;
```

Now Y3 holds the high bits from all eight outputs, Y2 holds the next bit from all eight outputs, and so on.  We just computed this function on eight different inputs using only four machine instructions!

Better yet, if our CPU is 32-bit (or 64-bit), we could compute this function on 32 (or 64) inputs, still using only four instructions.

Encoding the input and decoding the output to/from the "bit slice" representation takes some time, of course.  But for the right sort of function, this approach offers massive bit-level parallelism and thus a massive speedup.

The basic assumption is that you have many inputs (like 32 or 64) on which you want to compute the same function, and that the function is neither too hard nor too easy to represent as a bunch of Boolean operations.  (Too hard makes the raw computation slow; too easy makes the time dominated by the bit-slice encoding/decoding itself.)  For cryptography in particular, where (a) the data has to go through many "rounds" of processing, (b) the algorithm is often in terms of bits munging already, and (c) you are, for example, trying many keys on the same data...  It often works pretty well.

Comment: Thank you for this great description of bitslicing. But i don't understand how we could do matrix based permuation with this implementation. Sure, we use bitslice already for some parts of the code, but i have no idea how this could help us for permutations like the one i explained ...

Comment: @Thomas:  But permutations are simple.  In my example, bits x3 and x2 of each input are swapped (permuted) to produce the corresponding output...  And again, no matter what your function is (even a lookup table), there exists _some_ representation of it in terms of Boolean operations on the input bits.  (Boolean logic is universal.)

Comment: Please explain me: How could i move 128 64bit Inputs this style:
Input Bit 1 (for each of the 128) must to Output Bit 58 in 128 Different Outputs. And Bit 58 to bit 9 for example. You mentioned DES. Take the any permutation (not the sboxes) as example ;)

Comment: Are your registers 64 bit?  Then let's do 64 64-bit inputs instead.  First take bit 0 from _all_ 64 inputs and put them into one 64-bit word  X0.  Then take bit 1 from _all_ 64 inputs and put them into one 64-bit word X1.  And so on up to X63.  (Yes, this part is slow, but you only do it once.)  Now if output bit 9 needs to equal input bit 58, just set "Y9 = X58".  And so on.  At end, Y0 holds bit 0 of _all_ 64 outputs.  Y1 holds bit 1 of _all_ 64 outputs.  And so on.  You can do an arbitrary 64-bit permutation on 64 inputs with just 64 instructions...  _using the bit-slice encoding_

Comment: But i don't see where this is faster, then just do this for every bit, as i have to: 

*Transform 64 inbut strings
* Shift the Output Order
* Transform them back

Comment: Assuming you are taking the inputs through multiple stages (which for crypto, you surely are?), you can do the transform _once_ at the beginning, implement _all_ of the stages on the bit-slice representation, and then transform back _once_ at the end.  This is how the DES cracker worked...  DES has 16 "rounds".  They implemented all of the rounds to work directly on the bit-slice encoded form.  The cost of transforming input and output was more than made up for by the paralellism of the bit-slice implementation.

Comment: I could not find a full bitslice des implementation or any document that talks about that right now, maybe you have a link? All implementations i found has only bitslice sboxes

Comment: +1: I like the bit-slicing idea and have tried to compare the solutions (http://ideone.com/OYORo). It seems, that the bit-slicing advantage comes out when (as you mentioned) you want to combine more then one (not only permutation) function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems difficult to do the permutation in only one call. A special case of your problem, reversing bits in an integer, needs more than one 'call' (what do you mean by *call*?). See [Bit Twiddling Hacks by Sean](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel) for information of this example.

If your mapping pattern is not complicated, maybe you can find a fast way to calculate the answer:) However, I don't know whether you like this direct way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char mask[8];

//map bit to position
//0 -> 2
//1 -> 7
//2 -> 5
//...
//7 -> 6
unsigned char map[8] = {
    2,7,5,1,4,0,3,6
};


int main()
{
    int i;

    //input:
    //--------------------
    //bit 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
    //--------------------
    //val 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
    //--------------------
    unsigned char input = 0x26;

    //so the output should be 0xA1:
    //    1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
    unsigned char output;

    for(i=0; i<8; i++){ //initialize mask once
        mask[i] = 1<<i;
    }

    //do permutation
    output = 0;
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        output |= (input&mask[i])?mask[map[i]]:0;
    }

    printf("output=%x\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats the way we do it already. And thats slow if you have to do it with 100 MB input

Comment: And your example is one function call. We want to do combine the operations, as bitshifts are of high cost.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to look into some type of threading scheme ... either you can use a message-passing system where you send each block to a fixed set of worker threads, or you can possibly setup a pipeline with non-locking single producer/consumer queues that perform multiple shifts in a "synchronous" manner.  I say "synchronous" because a pipeline on a general-purpose CPU would not be a truly synchronous pipeline operation like you would have on a fixed-function device, but basically for a given "slice" of time, each thread would be working on one stage of the multi-stage problem at the same time, and you would "stream" the source data into and out of the pipeline.

Comment: Well, then you're not going to get any true parallelism ... no threads means that you will only be executing your code on a single core, and that single core cannot do two things at once.

Comment: Sry, i was a little bit unclear, i want to COMBINE the operations.

Comment: The bitslicing answer shows how a 64-bit CPU can do 64 bits in parallel.  The trick with all parallelism is where do you find it (threads, bit-parallel) and how do you harness it.